# How does less than operator behave differently from -le in BASH?

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
#!/bin/bash

a=10
b=30

[ $a -eq $b ]
echo $?

echo $(($a==$b))
```

This code outputs 1 then 0.
Why does $(($a==$b)) output 0?

I have tried this with -le and < also .

**[ $a -le $b ] ouputs 0**

**$(($a < $b)) outputs 1**

I have used both ksh and bash to check

Comment: You're comparing one component's _output_ with another's _exit status_. These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare the `$?` of one operation with the *output* of another. These are different things, because for *exit status* success is 0 and nonzero results reflect failure, but in a numeric context (such as that `$(( ))` enters), truth is 1 and failure is 0.

Compare your test with:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=10
b=30

[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
echo "Exit status using -eq: $?"

(( a == b ))
echo "Exit status using (( )): $?"
```

Output is correctly:

```
Exit status using -eq: 1
Exit status using (( )): 1
```

The changes I made (other than switching from `$(( ))` to `(( ))`) around quotes, `$`s, etc. were cosmetic with your current data -- they could change behavior with unexpected values, so I recommend using those practices in your code, but they don't actually modify immediate output.